# Piece de Resistance - Two Boxes, Two Boxes of Letters

Tags: word, letters, dominoes

### Two - Boxes, Two Boxes of Letters

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [**Two**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing) ...</sub>

<sub>Out of Character: Finally, a working... !</sub>

Once again you rub away the sivery coating, and you found a diagram:

[image: add image description]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*With a friendly nod to @jafe (who came very close), since an hour has gone by I figured it was fair game to post my own independent solution… Didn't want to be seen as sniping or piggy-backing!*

This is indeed a:

> [WorDonimoes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86762/introducing-wordonimoes2) puzzle, and has a solution in 17 moves.

As follows (double moves abridged in the diagram - read along each row; moves in square brackets can be carried out in an alternative order):

> [image]

Using the hint (“\ \”) and interpreting the title to imply that we are looking at two boxes of nine squares side by side, we should read down their diagonals to see the answer:

> LASHES

Answer (score 6):

> This looks to be a WorDonimoes puzzle (as introduced [last week](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86762)). The goal is to make a rectangle by moving dominoes around one by one without having adjacent dominoes touch on the same letter.
>
>  Not sure if there's a simpler way, but here's a solution with 21 steps.
>
>  [image]
>
>  The final position reads **LETHAL CANCER MESSES**. Since there's a "word" tag we're looking to produce a single word from this clue. Not sure what that could be yet...

Comment: Pretty sure sliding the TN sideways is an illegal move. The Wordomino puzzles require movement along the long axis only, don't they?

Comment: @Stiv Rats, I missed that restriction. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Splitting the result into two 3x3 boxes and reading down the diagonals gives LASHES.

Comment: @Deusovi Yes, I'd spotted that too - pretty sure that will turn out to be the answer...

Comment: all of your comments are correct!