# Piece de Resistance - Three Troublesome Toshes

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, acrostic

### Three - Troublesome Toshes

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [**Three**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing) ...</sub>

For the third time you removed the surface, and you saw three lines you couldn't make any sense of:

> $\text{Sad Wally, ugliest Alcatraz impala, mimeo abhorrer, lava continuo, kneels.}$
> $\text{Mean nerd met imperiled underservant; cuckoo kisses Ina Nagle.}$
> $\text{Met nerd, men worry cello neoclassicism negate Icaria tox lava.}$

### Gentle Reminder - May or May Not be Useful

> All letters are useful, but some letters are more useful than others.

Hint

usefulness level 1

> The number of useful letters within each word is the same.

usefulness level 2

> The number in Hint 1 is 2.

Comment: Could we get a hint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If you take the first and last letters of each word, you get the abbreviation for  a US state.  Then for each of the three lines, the states listed spell out a letter if you look at them on a map.

Sad Wally, ugliest Alcatraz impala, mimeo abhorrer, lava continuo, kneels.

> South Dakota, Wyoming, Utah, Arizona, Iowa, Missouri, Arkansas, Louisiana, Colorado, Kansas
>
>  spells out "A"
>  [image]

Mean nerd met imperiled underservant; cuckoo kisses Ina Nagle.

> Minnesota, North Dakota, Montana, Idaho, Utah, Colorado, Kansas, Iowa, Nebraska
>
>  spells out "G"
>  [image]

Met nerd, men worry cello neoclassicism negate Icaria tox lava.

> Montana, North Dakota, Minnesota, Wyoming, Colorado, New Mexico, Nebraska, Iowa, Texas, Louisiana
>
>  spells out "E"
>  [image]

So the answer is:

> AGE

Comment: Kudos for figuring out the puzzle, rot13(V fgvyy qba'g haqrefgnaq ubj gubfr fgngrf fcryy bhg gur yrggref 'N', 'T' naq 'R').

Comment: @Abbas I figured out how to embed images, so I added pictures to illustrate how the letters were formed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it from your previous comment, but the images are appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Considering the nonsense wording...

> I tried to pick out some letters that seem useful. The capitalised letters for each line are:
>  **SWA**
>  **MIN**
>  **MI**
>  Putting these together gets **SWAM IN MI**. Now **MI** is the abbreviation for Michigan.
>  Michigan is known for Lake Michigan.

Therefore I think the answer is:

> [Jim Dreyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Dreyer) who swam across Lake Michigan in 1998

Comment: nope... not like that... there is something called a LIMIT to which I can give you a hint...