# Piece de Resistance - Four Dots in a Line

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus

### Four - Dots in a Line

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) **[Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line)** [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing) ...</sub>

Looking for the next challenge, you got rid of the coating, and this time it amazed you, as it was a colour image with a beige background instead of the previous monochrome cards! Things are getting fun...

> [image]

Aha! And you vaguely found five short lines near the bottom of the card, in red ink...

### Hint

> Well, you expected 4 lines instead of 5, huh? Maybe look it up in a dictionary? Any other spellings? Oh, and just to say, the lines are something like this: 
> _ _ _ _ _

Comment: The two hints that were added (one here and one in the comments of my answer) to help with the conclusion are a bit disappointing. The puzzle was awesome up to that point but then it feels a bit far-fetched.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First panel:

> The top-left character is [Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(comics)), but with the two halves switched, so **kilo** (love that one). Then we have *groin $-$ Óin*, which leaves **gr**. The country is Armenia, so **am**: KILOGRAM

Second panel:

> The logo is the [Seal of the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Securities_and_Exchange_Commission), so **SEC**, **on** **D**: SECOND.

Third panel:

> [The **MET**](https://howlingpixel.com/i-en/List_of_tallest_buildings_in_Thailand), a building in Thailand, followed by the logo of Regal Cinemas minus that of the Galway County Council (GalwayCoco), so regal minus gal: **RE**. METRE

Fourth panel:

> A picture of [Americium (symbol Am)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium), "per e": AMPERE.

Now

> If you look into [the list of derived units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit#Derived_units_with_special_names) (credit to [@JProblems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60306/jproblems) in the comments for the idea), you see that the numbers from the axis ($-6, -2, 2, 4$) likely correspond to exponents, and since a **Volt** is $$1V=1m^2\cdot kg\cdot A^{-1}\cdot s^{-3}$$
>  it follows that the puzzle links to a **VOLT SQUARED**, with symbol **$V^2$**. To be noted, there is no reason given in the puzzle to think in volt squared rather than in another equivalent unit, such as **WATT OHM** ($1 V^2=1W\cdot \Omega$). One of these interpretations might explain what to do with the five red lines at the bottom of the card.

One way to conclude (unlikely):

> The five red lines may stand for a five-line staff, and link to music. There is a Spotify list called [Volt Squared](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3tQ0AWBWGZ2JY1RzRYm5Jo).

Another way to conclude (much better):

> Perhaps the five lines aren't straight, and actually shaped like "$/W$" (credits to [@hdsdv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61592/hdsdv) in the comments for this idea). In this case the final answer would be **OHM** (volt squared per watt). Note that it relates to the title of the series, *Piece de Resistance*, (since Ohm is the unit of resistance), and that it is consistent with the red ink used to write "per e" in the fourth panel.

A third conclusion given the hint that was added:

> The scale of the horizontal axis could be $1/2$ (credits to [@AHKieran](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52155/ahkieran) for this idea following the OP's hint in the comments below) in which case the exponents are half what we thought they were, and the answer (in five letters) is **VOLTS**. It could also be **VOLTA**, as Volts were named after Alessandro Volta, or something else given the hint of finding another spelling for the four-letter word VOLT.
>
>  Edit: the answer is indeed **VOLTE** as confirmed by the OP in the comments below, who thought that this was a possible spelling of Volt.

Comment: Perhaps rot13(gur yvfg bs qrevirq havgf sbhaq urer uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/FV_qrevirq_havg#Qrevirq_havgf_jvgu_fcrpvny_anzrf) would help you?

Comment: @JProblems Oh nice catch, thanks. I wasn't looking in this direction.

Comment: rot13(V grnpu n ovg bs qvzrafvbany nanylfvf, naq abgvprq n avpr pbeerfcbaqrapr jvgu gur ahzore yvar naq gur havgf lbh qrevirq.) I would have never solved the rebuses though!

Comment: rot13(Jung vs gur funcr bs gur 5 yvarf vf jung znggref - sbe rknzcyr gurl pbhyq or va gur funcr bs "/ J".)

Comment: @hdsdv Very nice idea! rot13(Gura gur nafjre gb gur chmmyr jbhyq or BUZ.) It's also consistent with rot13(Gur erq vax hfrq gb jevgr "cre r" va gur sbhegu cnary.)

Comment: no one says that one segment of the line stands for 1... perhaps...?

Comment: rot13(Rnpu yvar frtzrag pbhyq or n unys fb gur ahzoref ercerfragrq ol gur qbgf jbhyq or -3, -1, 1, 2 juvpu jbhyq yrnq gur nafjre gb fvzcyl or IBYGF)

Comment: @AHKieran That seems a bit far-fetched, but given the hint that was just added, could be.

Comment: @AHKieran Oh I hadn't seen that comment by the OP just above yours. Well, ok then.

Comment: oh, sorry... i thought volte was a variant spelling of volt... never mind, just add that as your answer... nicely done +1