# Piece de Resistance - Six-six-six. An Ultimate Wall of Cryptics

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues, connect-wall

### Six - six-six. An Ultimate Wall of Cryptics

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) **Six** ...</sub>

Aha! This one is of landscape orientation! Let's see...

> [image: cryptic clues on a wall background]

Hint 1:

> Title is hint.

Hint 2:

> Threaten chickens to be devils

Textual transcription of image, with clues in left-to-right and top-to-bottom order, for accessibility or copy-paste purposes:

> - Originally upset, Peter is awake (2)
> - Ultimate veto in switch position (2)
> - They opposed stating threats (3)
> - Intend to wrap up alibi and lead mystery (3)
> - Rub, ail, sit! (3)
> - Stalker's flag (4)
> - Light unit and lead to domain (4)
> - History within toothpaste (4)
> - Exclamation reversed purpose of shelter (5)
> - The fir among the trees (5)
> - Ring and veil uncovered reveals actress (5)
> - Mazed heart before an area (4)
> - Chicken! A searching over grass (5)
> - Settle public awareness (5)
> - O pal! Dim tangled qualification (7)
> - Deformed mint gel is changing form (7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suggested answers for all 16 cryptic clues follow below. Note that several of the clues employ 'printer's *devilry*' techniques, as suggested by '666', the mark of the beast from Revelation, appearing in the title.

*Originally upset, Peter is awake (2)*

> **UP** (‘originally’ as in ‘first letters of’ **U**pset, **P**eter, meaning *awake*)

*Ultimate veto in switch position (2)*

> **ON** (‘ultimately’ as in ‘last letters of’ vet**O** i**N**, meaning *switch position*)

*They opposed stating threats (3)*

> **EVA** (printers devilry: *They oppose d**EVA**stating threats*) - solved by @JS1 in comments

*Intend to wrap up alibi and lead mystery (3)*

> **AIM** (‘wrap up’ as in ‘ first and last letters of’ **A**lib**I** + ‘lead’ – first letter – of **M**ystery, meaning *intend*)

*Rub, ail, sit! (3)*

> **ION** (printers devilry: *Rub**IO N**ails it!*)

*Stalker’s flag (4)*

> **JACK** (double meaning: Jack, as of ‘and the beanstalk’ and ‘union jack’)

*Light unit and lead to domain (4)*

> **LAND** (‘**L**ight unit’ + **AND**, meaning *domain*)

*History within toothpaste (4)*

> **PAST** (‘within’ reveals ‘tooth**PAST**e’, meaning *history*)

*Exclamation reversed purpose of shelter (5)*

> **HOUSE** (‘**OH**’ reversed + **USE** (purpose), meaning *shelter*)

*The fir among the trees (5)*

> Either **STONE** (printers devilry: *The fir**ST ONE** among the trees*) - suggested by @hdsdv and @JS1 in comments

*Ring and veil uncovered reveals actress (5)*

> **OLIVE** ('ring' = **O** + an anagram of 'veil' clued by 'uncovered', i.e. **LIVE**, giving a female name which can be suggested by 'actress')

*Mazed heart before an area (4)*

> **ZONE** (‘heart’ as in ‘central letter of’ ‘ma**Z**ed’ + **ONE** (an, singular), meaning *area*)

*Chicken! A searching over grass (5)*

> (best guess at present) **PEACE** (printer's devilry: *Chicken **PEA CE**ase arching over grass*) - solved by @JS1 in comments

*Settle public awareness (5)*

> **LIGHT** (double meaning, as in 'settle', 'land', 'dismount' and also in 'public awareness', 'public knowledge', 'bringing to light') - solved by @JS1 in comments

*O pal! Dim tangled qualification (7)*

> **DIPLOMA** (anagram of ‘o pal dim’ clued by ‘tangled’, meaning *qualification*)

*Deformed mint gel is changing form (7)*

> **MELTING** (anagram of ‘mint gel’ clued by ‘deformed’, meaning *changing form*)

Taken all together, the 16 solutions then form:

> A connecting wall to resolve. The four answers are then connected as a group themselves, giving the final answer to the puzzle.

Resulting solution:

> **TIME** - ZONE (time zone), ON (on time), PAST (past time), UP (time up)
>   **HIGH** - AIM (aim high), LAND (highland), DIPLOMA (high diploma), LIGHT (highlight)
>  **POT** - ION (potion), JACK (jackpot), MELTING (melting pot), STONE (potstone)
>  **GREEN** - OLIVE (olive green), PEACE (Greenpeace),  HOUSE (greenhouse), EVA (Eva Green).
>
>  The final connection between the four groups is:
>
>  **TEA** - TIME (teatime), HIGH (high tea), POT (teapot), GREEN (green tea).

Comment: #10 (The fir...) could be rot13(cevagre'f qrivyel jvgu fbzrguvat yvxr FGBAR be FGNFU), but neither of those seem compelling enough to stand out as a definitive answer. I'm not really a cryptics person, just throwing that out there.

Comment: You know what @hdsdv I think you're right that that method will crop up in this puzzle (would explain the title) and maybe even about one of these suggestions specifically...

Comment: Despite the fact that Rubio is a puzzler, there is another [Rubio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Rubio) in real life. Don't accuse me of using Puzzlers' name >:)

Comment: I'm new around here but I swear that earlier I was thinking "what could rot13(Ehovb anvyf vg) possibly mean??"

Comment: rot13(Dhvpx tbbtyr frnepu erirnyf gurer ner frireny npgerffrf anzrq Byvir) -- but I too remain unconvinced!

Comment: rot13(Gur Gvzr Fgbar vf n guvat va gur Zneiry havirefr, fb znlor #10 vf gur bar zvffvat sebz gur "gvzr" tebhc?)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Can I confirm one element, please: rot13(Vf UVTU n pbeerpg jnyy tebhc, be fubhyq vg or UVTURE vafgrnq? Vs gur ynggre, qbrf QVCYBZN orybat va gung tebhc (naq V jbhyq gura nffhzr gung GRN vf gur jebat birenyy yvax)?)

Comment: @Stiv rot13(uvtu vf n tebhc anzr, naq qvcybzn orybatf gb vg)

Comment: @js1 rot13(vg vfag nve, naq gur nafjre bs gung pyhr vf abg va gur gvzr pngrtbel)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Can I confirm... rot13(Vf BYVIR pbeerpg? Vs fb, vf TERRA gur svany tebhc? Xabjvat gung zvtug uryc qrevir zvffvat nafjref!) Thanks!

Comment: @Stiv yes for both questions

Comment: Stiv and @OmegaKrypton: rot13(FGNFU pbhyq nyfb jbex vafgrnq bs FGBAR orpnhfr bs "cbg fgnfu".  V'z gelvat gb zxr CRNPR svg n pyhr gb znxr "terracrnpr" ohg gur orfg V pbhyq pbzr hc jvgu jnf "frggyr choyvp njnerarff": frggyr = crnpr, choyvp njnerarff = cbyvgvpny pbeerpgarff = cp = ubzbalz sbe crnpr.  Rira n ovttre ernpu jnf "Puvpxra crn, prnfr nepuvat bire tenff" cevagref qrivygel.)

Comment: @JS1 First part of your comment might be a good shout :) Certainly adds a little extra of relevance to the rest of the sentence. Would be interested to know the OP's intent...

Comment: Stiv and @OmegaKrypton rot13(V tbg bar: RIN = Gurl bccbfr qRINfgngvat guerngf (cevagref qrivygel), jurer RIN svgf va gur TERRA pngrtbel (Rin Terra npgerff).)

Comment: rot13(Creuncf "frggyr choyvp njnerarff" pbhyq or YVTUG nf n qbhoyr qrsvavgvba.  Vs lbh ybbx ng uggcf://jjj.zreevnz-jrofgre.pbz/qvpgvbanel/yvtug - qrsvavgvba 7n vf "choyvp xabjyrqtr" naq qrsvavgvba 2 bs ireo(2) vf "frggyr, nyvtug" (nf n oveq).  Vg jbhyq nyfb svg jvgu pngrtbel UVTU nf "uvtuyvtug".)

Comment: @JS1 I think you could be right on both these comments. Will build them both into the answer. Thanks!

Comment: rot13(Tvira gur ynfg pyhr 1) vf gur puvpxra bar 2) vf n cevagre'f qrivygel 3) vf 5 yrggref, 4) naq gur nafjre fubhyq svg jvgu GVZR, gur orfg V pbhyq qb jnf FCNPR: "PuvpxraF CNPR, n frnepuvat bire tenff".  Qbrfa'g ernyyl znxr frafr gubhtu.  Bgure jbeqf V gevrq gb svg (znlor lbh pna qb orggre): funer, fcner, crnpr, avtug, cevzr, senzr, yvzvg, fpnyr, qrynl, gevny, yncfr, furrg.)

Comment: youre so near! answer: rot13(TERRA: Ubhfr Byvir Rin Crnpr UVTU: Yvtug Ynaq Nvz Qvcybzn CBG: Wnpx Zrygvat Vba Fgbar GVZR: Mbar Hc Ba Cnfg)

Comment: @JS1 Thanks for your help! Since you got a quarter of the clues I reckon you should create your own partial answer with those 4 contributions, so you can get some bigger credit for your work...

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help on this hard one.  No need for credit...  I'm getting ready for part 7.

Comment: @js1 will be out very soon ;)