# Piece de Resistance - Seven Images Are Worth Digits

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

### Seven Images Are Worth Digits

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) **Seven** ...</sub>

Another colourful piece of work, this time on a white background, a bit more stretchy...

> [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is my somewhat crazy interpretation of the rebus, which is either correct or way off:

First image:

> The logo for Dash cryptocurrency, which I interpret as "-".

Second image:

> A picture of iodine, which I found with a reverse image search that led me to [this website](https://www.ijunoon.com/dictionary/iodine-Tagalog-meaning/) which has the same image.  I interpret this to be "i" which is iodine's chemical symbol.

Third image:

> This shows a chord with three g notes, but only the bottom note is highlighted.  I interpret this as low g, or stylistically: "log".

First image inside parentheses:

> Dash from the Incredibles movie.  I interpret this also as "-".

Second image inside parentheses:

> The right part of a bone.  I interpret this to be "one".

Putting it all together:

> You get $-i\log(-1)$.  It turns out that $\log(-1) = i\pi$, so substituting, you get $-i*i\pi$.  Now, because $i*i = -1$, the expression simply becomes $\pi$.  So I think the answer to the rebus is **pi**, which the title hints at because it has "digits".

Comment: The one commenting here is as crazy as you are. Nice job!