# Piece de Resistance - Eight Doubled Tetrominoes Make a Tetronogram

Tags: word, grid-deduction, polyomino, nonogram

### Eight Doubled Tetrominoes Make a Tetronogram

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) [Seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/piece-de-resistance-seven-images-are-worth-digits) **Eight** ...</sub>

*Time for Another Tetronogram! <sub>(named by @Feeds aka MrPie)</sub>*

> - The puzzle is made of a grid like a nonogram.
> - Notations are along the axes like a classic nonogram but numbers are replaced by the names of the tetromino.
> - The names are I, L, T, O, and S.
> - The tetrominoes can be flipped and rotated, therefore a J/Z tile would have the L/S notation.
> - A notation of ‘L’ means there is a part of the L tile on that row or column. It can be 1 tile, 2 tiles, or 3. Same theory for other tiles.
> - Most steps can be deduced by logic alone. There is only one solution, but only one make sense.
> - Not all grids have to be filled.
> - Different from other nonograms, there need not be a space between two tetrominoes.
> - Gray squares are shaded for you. There will not be any parts of a tetromino in those grids.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution(s)

I've solved the puzzle, but there seem to be two very slightly different possibilities for the final answer, differing only in what happens with two L-tetrominoes at the top in the middle:

> [image: first option]
>
>  [image: second option]

**Edit:** now that the question has been slightly edited to add another grey square, there's only one possibility left, which is the **second** of the two above. As @Stiv notes, this means the grey squares

> spell the word ODE.

### Reasoning

The first and easiest things to fill in are the

> I-tetrominoes, because there are only two columns and four rows which contain I cells. Then in the 4th row, all cells between the two I-tetrominoes must be empty (grey). In the bottom three rows, there's a T and an L between the two I-tetrominoes. The T can't go into the 4th column, and the L must be below the T in the 3rd column, so we get:
>
>  [image: bottom left done]

Next we fill in the

> T-tetromino in the top left, which is easy because it can't go into the 3rd column. For the L above it in the 2nd column, we can just make a start because we don't know whether it's three wide and two high or two wide and three high. (**Edit:** actually with the updated puzzle we know this for sure, but I'm going to continue with my original solution.)

Turns out that

> T-tetrominoes are also easy to solve. We've got part of one in the bottom row, which can only be in the 9th column. That T-tetromino can't go anywhere to the left, so there's only one possible orientation. In the 10th column we've got part of an S below that T, so there's only one possible orientation for this S-tetromino. Then the remainder of the bottom three rows is easy to fill:
>
>  [image: bottom finished]

Considering again T-tetrominoes:

> there must be part of one in the last column, which can only be in the 4th row, and then there's only one possible orientation for that T-tetromino. The next thing to the left of that must be an S-tetromino, which can't now be in the 10th or 11th columns, so we shade a few cells grey. Then a couple of L-tetrominoes are easy to place and we've finished the top right:
>
>  [image: top right done]

Now consider

> S-tetrominoes. There must be part of one in the 9th column. The 8th column must contain *two* different S-tetrominoes, one of which extends to the right and the other to the left. The 7th column only contains one S-tetromino, so the one that's in the 9th column must stop at the 8th. Then there's only one possible orientation for both S-tetrominoes:
>
>  [image: almost finished]

Then there's just two L-tetrominoes left to finish, which gives the two different possibilities shown at the top.

Comment: I imagine the second is the intended answer since the blankspace seems to spell a 3-letter word...