# Piece de Resistance - Nine is Three Tripled

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, tribond

### Nine is Three Tripled

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) [Seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/piece-de-resistance-seven-images-are-worth-digits) [Eight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/piece-de-resistance-eight-doubled-tetrominoes-make-a-tetronogram) **Nine**...</sub>

Here is the transcription of the card...

**Phase I - Truly. Tribond.**

> Bubonic
>   Egypt
>   Dogs

**Phase II - Insert! Interpretation?**

> My leader was once, in short, an elementary British theatre.
>   My fellows achieve, register, and branch.
>   My tail is a Shetland fiddle.
>   And Quebecois use me to insert!

**Phase III - Solution - Stepping Stone!**

**Hints**

> See Edit ;)

> 3, ..., 9

> The whole thing has been solved. Anyone care to answer it?

Comment: That hint seems self-referential ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, it's not.

Comment: The first section is pretty clearly rot13(cynthr (ohobavp cynthr, gra cynthrf bs rtlcg, cynthr qbtf)), but I have no idea what the second could be.

Comment: Im out of ideas. Here are my thoughts: Rot13(gur Ertvfgre vf n ybt (n ybt pna oenapu gbb), Furgynaq svqqyr vf n thr. fb jr trg -ybthr... ab pyhr nobhg gur gurngre cneg. Sbe cneg 3, gur fgrccvat fgbar vf arrqrq gb cnff n evire, thr va serapu vf n fznyy cnffntr gb pebff n evire. Znlor jr frnepu gur jbeq thr. Ab vqrn ubj gur Uvag jvgu gur pncvgnyf pbzrf vagb cynl.)

Comment: Rot13(V guvax "cynthr" vf evtug naq nyfb "___ybthr" sebz Onanaraxbcc.  V guvax gur uvag zvtug ersre gb "Centhr" (n pncvgny pvgl) juvpu svgf jvgu nyy gur "thr" jbeqf.  Gur Dhrorpbvf irefr zvtug or "rg" orpnhfr gung zrnaf "naq" va Serapu.  Be vg zvtug or "pnerg" orpnhfr gung vf hfrq gb vafreg grkg.)

Comment: To add to others' thoughts: rot13(Na 'ryrzragnel' Oevgvfu gurnger pbhyq or gur Ybaqba CNYYNQVHZ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encouraged by the third hint I'll give a try

### Phase I (solved by @Deusovi)

> Tribond riddle:
>  - *bubonic* **plague**
>  - ten **plague**s of *egypt*
>  - **plague** *dogs*

### Phase II - Insert! Interpretation?

> Riley riddle

My leader was once, in short, an elementary British theatre.

> An 'elementary' British theatre could be the London PALLADIUM.. (as suggested by @Stiv)
>  Palladium has the chemical element symbol "Pd"
>  From Omega Krypton Comment: Palladium used to be **Pl** in the early 19th century.

My fellows achieve, register, and branch.

> **log**: a register is a log, a log can branch too

My tail is a Shetland fiddle.

> A [**Gue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gue)
>
>  So we have Pl-log-gue -> **Plogue**

And Quebecois use me to insert!

> the french word "**plogue**" means "plug", to plug in means to insert

### Phase 3: Solution - Stepping Stone!

> Stepping stone = word ladder
>
>  Looking at the source code of the question we find "Look out for capitals."
>  Well, having two words ending with -gue we find the capital of the Czech Republic, **Prague**  (thx to @JS1)
>
>  Phase 1: Plague
>  Phase 2: Plogue
>  Phase 3: Prague
>  So 3 -> 1 -> 2 is a word ladder

### Solution

> **Prague**

### Bonus

> A stepping stone is needed to pass a river, **gue** in french is a small passage to cross a river.

### Title - Nine is Three Tripled

> Riddle 9 is divided into three parts

Comment: rot13(Cnyynqvhz hfrq gb unir gur purzvpy flzoby Cy...)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I'm confused.  Was the answer rot13(thr)?

Comment: could you please state more clearly that the final answer is prague? (stepping stone in the sene of word-ladder). thanks!