# Piece de Resistance - Ten Quotas. Nine Passed. Your Turn

Tags: pattern, visual, password

### Ten Quotas. Nine Passed. Your Turn

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) [Seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/piece-de-resistance-seven-images-are-worth-digits) [Eight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/piece-de-resistance-eight-doubled-tetrominoes-make-a-tetronogram) [Nine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89105/piece-de-resistance-nine-is-three-tripled) **Ten**...</sub>

Hmm... this is... a comic strip??

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> ESL

Because

> For each price tag, you should try to speak them out...
>  And notice the initials!
>
>  **T**wo **H**undred **E**uros
>  **S**ixteen **T**housand **E**leven **W**ons
>  ...
>  **E**ighty **N**ine **D**ollars
>  **E**ighty **S**even **L**evs