# Piece de Resistance - Queen Machina, my Majesty, Time for a Hearty Supper!

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

### Queen Machina, my Majesty, Time for a Hearty Supper!

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) [Seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/piece-de-resistance-seven-images-are-worth-digits) [Eight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/piece-de-resistance-eight-doubled-tetrominoes-make-a-tetronogram) [Nine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89105/piece-de-resistance-nine-is-three-tripled) [Ten](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89350/piece-de-resistance-ten-quotas-nine-passed-your-turn) [**Queen**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89546/piece-de-resistance-queen-machina-my-majesty-time-for-a-hearty-supper) [King](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90024/piece-de-resistance-king-deusovi-flag-this-blody-post)... [Jack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90172/piece-de-resistance-jack-in-all-tags-but-master-in-all)</sub>

No more images... (for the time being), back to words...

> $\mathfrak{\text{- rosin control}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{- escape talk}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{- current bond}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{- smallest direction}}$
>   $\mathfrak{\text{- unpleasant garbage}}$

**Rest Assured**

1) No obscure words

2) No P.SE usernames involved

3) The answer is a word. The title will make some sense when the answer is found.

**Hints**

Level 1

> "Unpleasant garbage" can be replaced by "unpleasant mess".

Level 2

> As some of you have suspected in the comments, this puzzle has nothing to do with [rhyme](/questions/tagged/rhyme).

Level 3:

> @PiIsNot3 has already correctly identified the logic. 2 more to go!

Level 4:

> "Unpleasant garbage" can be replaced by "strict code".

Comment: Think I can spot a few of these but wanted to check something... 'spran' - definitely the intended spelling?? Thanks!

Comment: @Stiv Copy and Paste it out or look at the source... weird font

Comment: @Bananenkopp D'oh, I see it now! Thanks...

Comment: Huh, no Jack? That's strange.

Comment: @Deusovi I checked in chat, and that was intentional.

Comment: Would it help if I put up the puzzle in a normal font as an answer or comment?

Comment: Supper... does it hint that the answer is food?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt to tie this up... As already established, the clues here refer to:

> Pairs of words whose spellings differ by the removal of a letter.

*rosin control*

> RE[S]IN - REIN

*escape talk*

> CH[E]AT - CHAT

*current bond (formerly 'spray heart')*

> TI[D]E - TIE

*smallest direction*

> WE[E]ST - WEST (found by @PilsNot3 - the two of us both discovered the same solutions to the first two clues independently but I had favoured [L]EAST - EAST here until attempting to spell the linking word out...)

*unpleasant garbage (or 'strict code' in hints)*

> HA[R]SH - HASH

Taking the 'unshared' letters from each pair suggests a solution of:

> **SEDER** - a Jewish ritual service and ceremonial dinner, which would link with 'supper' in the title. Not sure on the 'Queen Machina' reference - isn't she a Power Rangers baddie?!

Comment: got the last one, not the middle! edited q to get the same answer

Answer (score 5):

**Partial**

I believe the phrases clue

> pairs of words that differ by one letter, with the second word having one fewer letter than the first.

$ \mathfrak{\text{rosin control}} $

> RESIN REIN (?)

$ \mathfrak{\text{escape talk}} $

> CHEAT CHAT

$ \mathfrak{\text{spray heart}} $

> ??? ???

$ \mathfrak{\text{smallest direction}} $

> WEEST WEST

$ \mathfrak{\text{unpleasant garbage}} $

> ??? ???

Then, perhaps we

> take the letter that is subtracted in each phrase to get our final answer, which currently gives us SE?E?

Comment: I suggest rot13((Y)RNFG) rather than rot13(J(R)RFG).

Comment: Though it's amusing that both seem somewhat credible.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Hmm, definitely sounds plausible too - I'll take a second look at it and see what I find

Comment: Hmm, if we use rot13(FCEVGM/FCVEVG) for #3, where rot13(obgu pna ybfr n yrggre) then maybe yours is better than mine because it might lead to something like rot13(FRVMRF) though I don't see either #5 or a title link yet.

Comment: Feels like maybe too many degrees of freedom, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I did some thesaurus digging and couldn't find anything substantial to support the opposite direction, although I did come up with rot13(PENC FPENC (cneqba zl ynathntr)) for #5. And I do agree that that's probably too many for #3, but I couldn't find anything better either. Maybe the OP's memory will be jogged by this and can provide a hint?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If we take Gareth's rot13(FCEVGM/FCVEVG tvivat M naq V) and PilsNot3's rot13(FPENC/PENC tvivat F) leading to Gareth's guess of (FRVMRF), I would like to point out that rot13(Va Serapu, "frvmr" zrnaf "fvkgrra", fb znlor fhccre vf ng 16:00?).  It still doesn't explain why the Queen is named "Machina" though.

Comment: I guess rot13(DHRRA, ZNPUVAR naq FVKGRRA nyy eulzr jvgu bar nabgure)...

Comment: For 5, how about something like rot13(SVYGU(L) SVYGU)? Though can't quite spot a valid linkword with that letter in there...

Comment: unpleasant garbage could be rot13(purnc urnc)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I think the removed letter is supposed to be the middle one (the "heart", as in the title).

Comment: With the new hint I think 5 could be rot13(unefu unfu). The second word also means "mess".

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:
- unpleasant garbage

> messy mess

Final Word:

> Should it be SE?EY?