# Piece de Resistance - King Deusovi, Flag this Blo*dy Post!

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, pattern, rebus, steganography

### King Deusovi, Flag this Blo*dy Post!

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) [Seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/piece-de-resistance-seven-images-are-worth-digits) [Eight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/piece-de-resistance-eight-doubled-tetrominoes-make-a-tetronogram) [Nine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89105/piece-de-resistance-nine-is-three-tripled) [Ten](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89350/piece-de-resistance-ten-quotas-nine-passed-your-turn) [Queen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89546/piece-de-resistance-queen-machina-my-majesty-time-for-a-hearty-supper) [**King**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90024/piece-de-resistance-king-deusovi-flag-this-blody-post) [Jack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90172/piece-de-resistance-jack-in-all-tags-but-master-in-all)</sub>

Hmmm, what is this?

> [image]

P.S.: [word](/questions/tagged/word) tag also applies.

Clarification:

> The WHITE border of the image is NOT part of the puzzle.

Hint level 1:

> ONLY the WHITE border of the image is NOT part of the puzzle. [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) only applies [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)ly.

Comment: Can I check something that will sound totally weird if the answer is no... rot13(Vf gur ahzore 1234567 vzcbegnag gb gur fbyhgvba?)

Comment: where is that number? @Stiv

Comment: Well, I got a super weird coincidence trying to fathom out the fifth box (I had the rest) - rot13(Vs lbh pbaireg gur yrggref gb N1M26 lbh pbhyq trg I3E/E = IIIE/E = 22222218/18 juvpu rdhnyf 1234567.6...). It just seemed too weird a coincidence and I got bogged down trying to work out why that be! Clearly not the way to solve it though, I'm guessing...

Comment: rot13(Qbhoyr purpx ba jurgure gurer vf n zvfgnxr va gur 5gu obk: Vs gur sbezhyn jrer I^3/E^2, gung jbhyq znxr CV (C = I^2/E naq V = I/E, fb C * V = I^3/E^2).)

Comment: @JS1 ughhhh! my math...

Comment: @JS1 Well deduced - that was precisely the value I was trying to derive also for the sequence!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Title

> From Title "**flag** this blo*ody post"
>  The colors blue and red remind me of two flags
>  - the [Flag of Liechtenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Liechtenstein). The crown within could be referenced by the title word "king"...
>  - The [Signal flag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags) for **E** (ECHO)

### Upper half (blue)

> There are some hidden words: Ace ice oar Oman over
>  They are written upside down from right to left
>  Searching for a pattern, I tried adding letters forming new words:
>  Adding **R** gives **R**ace, **R**ice, **R**oar, **R**oman, **R**over

### Lower half (red) Rebus:

First red square

> - ace of spades - short **A**
>  - Elephant
>  - 3/4 of a cent - c**ent**
>  -> Remove **ent** from *E*l*e*pha*nt* -> lpha
>
>  **Alpha**

Second red square

> - The land on the map is **Tibet**
>  - The lower left image is the logo of Texas Instruments - **TI**
>  - [Ammeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter) - An instrument to measure the current (in **A**mpere)
>  -> Remove **TI** from *Ti*bet -> **bet**
>  -> add **A** to bet
>  **beta**

Fourth red Square

> - A 1915 Ford Model **T**
>  - A balloon flying with a child... must be filled with Helium, Chemical Symbol is **He**
>  - A Taxi
>  - An image of the chinese president **Xi** Jinping
>  Remove **Xi** from Ta*xi* -> Ta
>
>  T He Ta -> **Theta**

Fifth red Square (Solved by JS1)

> $P = V \times I$ ([Formula of Electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power)) and $I = \frac{V}{R}$
>  $=> \frac{V^3}{R^2} = \frac{V^2}{R} \times \frac{V}{R} = P \times I = PI$
>  **Pi**

Now back to the third square: (Solved by Stiv)

> We have
>  1. $\alpha$ (Alpha, 1. Letter of the Greek Alphabet)
>  2. $\beta$ (Beta, 2. Letter of the Greek Alphabet)
>  3. ?
>  4. $\theta$ (Theta, 8. Letter of the Greek Alphabet)
>  5. $\pi$ (Pi, 16. Letter of the Greek Alphabet)
>  Now, it looks like the position of the letter is doubled in each square so the third should be
>  $\delta$ (**D**elta, 4. Letter)

Conclusion (thx to M Oehm & Stiv)

> **E** from Echo-flag
>  **R** from the hidden words
>  **D** from 3. red square Delta
>  ERD anagrams to **RED**, fitting the bloody Hint from the title

Comment: rot13(Ynfg erq fdhner ybbxf yvxr na ryrpgebavpf sbezhyn, nafjre pbhyq or bzrtn, gur flzoby sbe erfvfgnapr)

Comment: FWIW, rot13(NYCUN, ORGN, GURGN naq CV ner gur 1fg, 2aq, 8gu naq 16gu yrggref bs gur Terrx nycunorg. Vs gur zvffvat flzoby vf vaqrrq gur 4gu (fvapr vg'f n qbhoyvat frdhrapr) guvf jbhyq or QRYGN. V fgvyy pnaabg frr ubj gb gvr guvf va jvgu gur synt be gur E frpgvba...)

Comment: rot13(Vs lbh ghea gur pbagenfg nyy gur jnl hc, gurer ner fbzr erq/oyhr qnfurf gung fubj hc va gur qvivqre orgjrra gur erq/oyhr cnegf.  Gurl ebhtuyl ybbx yvxr: 1) fznyy erq qnfu ba evtug bs 1fg obk, 2) Zrqvhz erq qnfu ba yrsg bs 2aq obk, 3) Zrqvhz oyhr qnfu ba zvqqyr bs 2aq obk, 3) Zrqvhz erq qnfu ba yrsg bs 3eq obk, 4) Ybat erq qnfu ba zvqqyr bs 4gu obk, 5) Fubeg erq qnfu ba evtug bs 4gu obk, jurer fubeg = yratgu 1, zrqvhz = 2, ybat = 3)

Comment: @JS1 i cant see the dashes, therefore they are irrelevant ;)

Comment: @Bananenkopp youve got all the pieces. so what is the answer?

Comment: If Stiv's assumption is right – and it sounds plausible – rot13(jr unir gur Q sebz gur cubargvp nycunorg. Gbtrgure jvgu gur Rpub synt naq gur E, guvf zvtug tvir gur nafjre).

Comment: @MOehm Reckon the answer could be the 3 combined? i.e. rot13(ERQ)?

Comment: @Stiv: Perhaps. It would fit the asterisked word in the title.

Comment: @MOehm True! Bananenkopp, fancy adding the last few comments above into your post?