# Piece de Resistance - Jack in all Tags... But Master in All?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, metapuzzles

### Jack in all Tags... But Master in All?

<sub>This puzzle is part of the "Piece de Resistance" series. Go back to Part 1 (Ace) for the story.
[Ace](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86871/piece-de-resistance-introduction-ace-and-as) [Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86924/piece-de-resistance-two-boxes-two-boxes-of-letters) [Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/piece-de-resistance-three-troublesome-toshes) [Four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87049/piece-de-resistance-four-dots-in-a-line) [Five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/piece-de-resistance-five-flowers-with-one-missing/) [Six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87580/piece-de-resistance-six-six-six-an-ultimate-wall-of-cryptics/) [Seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/piece-de-resistance-seven-images-are-worth-digits) [Eight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/piece-de-resistance-eight-doubled-tetrominoes-make-a-tetronogram) [Nine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89105/piece-de-resistance-nine-is-three-tripled) [Ten](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89350/piece-de-resistance-ten-quotas-nine-passed-your-turn) [Queen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89546/piece-de-resistance-queen-machina-my-majesty-time-for-a-hearty-supper) [King](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90024/piece-de-resistance-king-deusovi-flag-this-blody-post)... **[Jack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90172/piece-de-resistance-jack-in-all-tags-but-master-in-all)**</sub>

You finally flipped to your last card, and... a bunch of animals??? Tis' not Animal Farm, right?

> [image: nothing here...]

### OP's Words

This has been a fun series, seeing you guys solving a variety of puzzles, awing at how you guys can all *[literally]* read my mind. This puzzle may not be as majestic as @jafe's Gladys series, nor may it be as themed as @athin's Pyramid series. Yet I hope y'all have fun in this, and feel free to give me some feedback for my puzzle-creating skills. Thank you all for solving my puzzles, because it's no use making puzzles while no one is solving it. As a final word, as I've always said, "Happy Puzzling"!

Comment: Can you confirm the answers to Three and Nine? Three's answer seems like it should be ADE with the data I have so far, but you accepted AGE. And I haven't been able to get the answer to Nine to work.

Comment: (And can you check the placement of the emoji near the upper left?)

Comment: @Deusovi 3 is AGE. 9 is PRAGUE. the emojis should be alright

Comment: Ah, that fixes it! I think I see how the rest of the puzzle works - writing it up now.

Comment: @Deus oh no... you're just so gaddam quick...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, the numbers:

> The given grid can be solved as a colored nonogram. (The X marks an unshaded cell.)
>
>  [image]

Next, we use the emoji:

> The twelve emoji are the twelve animals of the Chinese zodiac. These have a canonical order, so we can match them up with our twelve answers.
>  Then, the twelve answers can be entered into the grid crossword-style: each one goes across or down, starting from its square. There's only one way to do this.
>  [image]

And finally, we use both parts of the data we've gathered so far.

> The given squares are always in groups of 2 or 3, either horizontally or vertically. And there's a single red piece, in the same row as the arrow on the right... Turns out that these form a Rush Hour puzzle. In Rush Hour, there are several cars of length 2 or 3 in a grid - they can only move forwards or backwards. One of the cars is red, and the goal is to get it out.

Solving that puzzle, and getting a final answer:

> Here's the solution to the Rush Hour puzzle:
>  [image]
>  Each of the cars was filled with letters. In the solved position, these spell out the final answer:
>  [image]
>  And with that, we've **SOLVED THE LAST PIECE**!

Comment: Well, that's my evening freed up! Nice solve +1 And nice finale @OmegaKrypton - sweet meta-mechanism ("metanism"?!) :)